# Is "nargile" known in English spoken countries to be related to "hookah"?

Tags: word-usage

Is *nargile* known in English spoken countries to be related to *hookah*?

I checked in Wiki and I didn't see any mention of that name, but in other dictionaries I saw the word nargile, but it's not clear to me how much it is in use or known in English spoken countries.

Comment: I like _sheesha_ or the charming _hubble-bubble_ myself. But _hookah_ is the common usage.

Answer (score 5):

The term *hookah* is much more commonly used in English, and there is a good chance that most people would know what it means, whereas most people would have to look up *nargile* (or *narghile*, *nargileh*) in a dictionary. I have only come across it once in my reading (as far as I can recall). Here are the relative frequencies of *hookah*, *narghile*, *nargileh* and *nargile* according to Google:

[image]

As you can see, *hookah* is the clear winner.

[Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hookah%2Cnarghile%2Cnargileh%2Cnargile&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chookah%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnarghile%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnargileh%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnargile%3B%2Cc0)